# Alineación en la impresión de un ticket desfasado

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy configurando mi ticketera (en la cual uso `PrintDialog`), por lo cual necesito darle un margen de caracteres permitidos a mis datos e insertas espacios en blanco en el espacio sobrante. Mi problema es que probe con los metodos `PadLeft` y `PadRight` para realizar lo anteriormente mencionado en un programa de consola, el cual me funciono correctamente, pero cuando lo implemente en la ticketera, me lo imprime mal (cruzado), ¿a que se podra deber? ¿Se puede alinear eficientemente con otro metodo?
Link de la ticketera: [Ticketera](https://lycaiospos.com/producto/impresora-termica-xprinter-58mm-usb/#tab-description)

Resultado en consola (el primero es manual, los otros 3 son calculados):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo de prueba en consola:

```
        string Plato1 = "Sprite";
        string Plato2 = "Sandwitch de milanesa";
        string Plato3 = "Coca cola";
        string Cantidad1 = "12";
        string Cantidad2 = "3";
        string Cantidad3 = "732";
        string Subtotal = "$123.00";
        string Subtota2 = "$23462,00";
        string Subtota3 = "$1353.00";

        Console.WriteLine("Nombre                 Cant. Subtotal");
        Console.WriteLine("Sandwitch de milanesa | 245 |$1200.00");

        Console.WriteLine($"{Plato1.PadRight(22)}{Cantidad1.PadLeft(5)}{Subtotal.PadLeft(10)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{Plato2.PadRight(22)}{Cantidad2.PadLeft(5)}{Subtota2.PadLeft(10)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{Plato3.PadRight(22)}{Cantidad3.PadLeft(5)}{Subtota3.PadLeft(10)}");
```

Codigo de la ticketera donde asigno y creo el `DrawString`:

```
                string Nombre = Convert.ToString(dgvArticulosPedido.Rows[Indice].Cells[1].Value);
                string Cantidad = Convert.ToString(dgvArticulosPedido.Rows[Indice].Cells[2].Value);
                string Subtotal = Convert.ToString($"${Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(dgvArticulosPedido.Rows[Indice].Cells[4].Value), 2)}");

                e.Graphics.DrawString($"{Nombre.PadRight(27)}{Cantidad.PadLeft(6)}{Subtotal.PadLeft(11)}", FuenteCuerpo, Pincel, ComienzoX, ComienzoY + Compensar);
```

Imagen del resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que tipo de impresora es?  Impresora de punto o impresora térmica?

Comment: A mi me paso eso y era un driver , no era el código. Hay un driver que es generic text   que funciona bien en algunos casos y hay uno que no recuerdo el nombre pero es como dotnetprint o algo así que es específico para impresoras de punto porque esas impresoras  no funcionan bien con .net si no se instala ese driver.

Comment: Perdon, me olvide de poner el link de la ticketera, ya esta agregado. Es una termina XPrinter 58mm

Comment: No se si se puede deber a que las letras del ticket son diferentes a la de consola y ocupan mas espacio, y por eso se genera mas diferencia de posiciones en el eje X

Comment: Si, el problema es por lo que puse en el ultimo mensaje, pero no quiero imprimir 3 lineas para cada cosa en cada artiulo, ¿como lo podria solucionar?